# Passing a fixed length buffer to a function as an argument without using GCHandle.Alloc

Tags: c#, optimization, interop

**How can one pass the contents of a fixed-length buffer to a function in C# without having to use GCHandle.Alloc to pin a managed object?**

I have structs that look more or less like this, with fixed buffers used for interoperability with a C++ data source:

```cs
public unsafe struct Person
{
    public ulong id;
    public fixed byte firstName[20];
    public fixed byte lastName[20];
}
```

I need to be able to pass a buffer into a converter function that converts it into a regular string. This function looks like this:

```cs
public unsafe class BufferConverter : IValueConverter<object, string>
{
    public string Convert(object value, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(value, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr dataPtr = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(dataPtr);
    }

    . . .
}
```

Currently I'm able to make this work by boxing the buffer, passing the boxed object as an argument, and then unboxing the object and converting the pointer to a string.

**This is way too slow.** I have to process hundreds of millions of these strings, and `GCHandle.Alloc` is taking up way too much time.

My question: is there any way to do this without needing to use `GCHandle.Alloc`? IOW, what's the most performant way of doing this? It would be much quicker to just pass the raw buffer without having to box/unbox it, but as far as I know, [there's no way to do that in C# yet.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1320)

Comment: Just don't box, it is not necessary.  A struct passed as an argument or stored in a local variable does not require pinning since it isn't stored on the GC heap.  So use Convert(Person person) { string first = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)(&person.firstName)); // etc...}

Comment: I'm not passing the struct here is the thing, I'm trying to pass the field itself. I'll try reworking my code to pass the struct, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the pointer to `IntPtr` and pass it to the converter like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

unsafe
{
    var p = new Person();
    *p.firstName = 66;
    
    var str = Convert((IntPtr) p.firstName);
    Console.WriteLine(str); // B

    static string Convert(IntPtr value)
    {
        return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(value);
    }
}

public unsafe struct Person
{
    public ulong id;
    public fixed byte firstName[20];
    public fixed byte lastName[20];
}
```